# Broken wordpress permalinks on pages only

Tags: permalinks, pages

Not sure when it happened but the custom permalinks for pages on my client's Wordpress site have broken. I can fix it by reverting back to the default permalinks and then using the custom permalinks, but they break again whenever my clients edits a page. Blog posts, archives, tags, categories, and custom post types permalinks all work fine, it's only pages that 404 when using custom permalinks.

The site has an .htaccess file with 666 permissions with the following in the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It also has mod_rewrite enabled.

Using Wordpress 3.1.3

It's not the plugins because I have disabled all of them and the permalinks for pages still don't work.

Please help.

Comment: I would recommend not using 666 as a file permissions, especially if there are other users on the same server. Also rename the .htaccess to old.htaccess and click default permlinks, then click your custom structure 2x, then check if WordPress has written a new .htaccess and compare it to the old one.

Comment: @Wyck I generated new .htaccess several times by doing what you said. It still 404's when I edit a page and the .htaccess file has the same code in it. The .htaccess file is currently 644.

Comment: Does the same thing occur with the default twentyten theme and all plugins disabled?

Comment: It works fine in the TwentyTen theme with all plugins enabled (didn't try disabled). That means there is something wrong with the theme then doesn't it? Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: It's impossible to say, try contact the theme author, if you have to start looking in functions.php for anything weird.

Comment: Ha, I am the theme author. I deleted functions.php and the problem still persists so it's not that. I also tried deleting all java and jquery code from the header just for the heck of it, didn't do anything. Any other ideas? If it helps, this is the website in question. It's the first theme I built from scratch so the code isn't very pretty (fair warning). http://seejanedirect.com/

Comment: Have you tried several permalink structures, such as just using `%postname`. You can see some here http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Yes, using anything other than the default makes the page 404 after editing and saving it.

Comment: I actually was recently making changes to a PremiumPress theme and had a similar issue. Randomly getting a 404 when you edited a post, page, or anything. I found that my issue was an infinite `add_action()` loop. Look for anywhere that you called `add_action()` or `add_filter()` and make sure the callback function doesn't run any core WordPress functions which would call the same hook or filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the [Custom Post Type UI Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and had generated the following code (which I added to the functions file) for a custom taxonomy through the plugin:

```
register_taxonomy( 'video_type',
    array ( 0 => 'video' ),
    array( 
        'hierarchical'    => true,
        'label'           => 'Type',
        'show_ui'         => true,
        'query_var'       => true,
        'rewrite'         => array( 'slug' => '' ),
        'singular_label'  => 'video_type'
```

Somehow that code broke the theme. In Custom Post Type UI you can either create custom posts types and taxonomies and keep the plugin active or use the beta function to copy and paste generated code to your function file. So I ended up deleting that code and keeping the plugin active.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a custom post type? This is exactly the kind of behavior you will see from have a custom post type with a slug that matches the slug of your pages. For example, if you have a page called "portfolio" and a post type called "portfolio", both with a slug of "portfolio", 404s are going to be thrown for some of these.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a client's Wordpress installation after a malicious attack. The .htaccess file had been tampered with and the theme's functions.php had a new obfuscated function at the top of the file.

Reverting to the standard .htaccess file and removing the offending function fixed the problem for me.

(Of course, that's not to say other files were not compromised.)